# An inequality regarding projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be two normalized vectors such that $a^T b << 1$. Define matrix $C$ such that $[a, b, C]$ is full column rank, and let matrix $D$ be positive definite. Define projection matrix $P_A:=A (A^T A)^{−1}A^T$. Can we say the following?

$$\frac{a^T D^{-1/2}\left(I - P_{D^{-1/2}C}\right)D^{-1/2}b}{
\left\|\left(I - P_{D^{-1/2}C}\right)D^{-1/2}b\right\|_2
\left\|\left(I - P_{D^{-1/2}C}\right)D^{-1/2}a\right\|_2
}<< 1$$
where $<<$ is the little-$o$ notation.

Also [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2698493/195455) on MSE.

Comment: When $A$ is full column rank, $A^TA$ is nonsingular, not necessarily $AA^T$. So your definition of $P_A$ is not true.

Comment: A mistake on the projection. Corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., let $a=-[1,0,0]^T$, $b=[0,1,0]^T$, $D=I_3$, and $C=[1,1,t]^T$ for $t>0$. Then $a^Tb=0<<1$ and the orthoprojector matrix onto the column space of $A=D^{-1/2}C$ is $P_A=CC^T/(2+t^2)$, whereas your ratio is $\frac1{1+t^2}\to1$ as $t\to0$, which is not $<<1$.

Comment: In your example, the left-hand side is negative and much smaller than the RHS, so the inequality may hold (just may not be tight). I have modified the question in light of your Remarks 1 and 2.

Comment: @Jeff : If you take $a=-[1,0,0]^T$ rather than $a=[1,0,0]^T$, then your ratio will go to $1$ as $t\to0$. So, your ratio will not be $<<1$.

Comment: @Jeff : I have edited the answer in accordance with my comment above.